# Analyze misclassifications

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, boosting

I've trained a classification model (XGBoost) but I'm having some issues with misclassification (especially false positive). I want to analyze the misclassified observations to see if the model misses any aspects of the data. What is a feasible method to do so?

I've been thinking about conducting logistic regression where the dependent variable will be a variable indicating if the observation was misclassified or not (all, false negative, false positive). Is that an appropriate approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Compare the prediction to the labels. Mark the misclassified observations. Do some exploratory analysis to know whether the model misses anything that you can detect.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 Sorry for being unclear. That is my intention. What exploratory analysis do you suggest more specifically?

Comment: Scatter plot and box/density plot. Pair plot might be an option if the number of features is high.

Comment: It's important to evaluate the details of the probability model rather than just the final classifications. The classifications depend not only on the probabilities returned by the model but also on the probability threshold chosen as the cutoff, usually a hidden default of 0.5 for a binary classification. You can cut down on the number of false positives by changing that threshold, even with the same model. It is possible for XGBoost to return probabilities rather than simply the classifications.

Comment: @EdM Thanks for the suggestion. But I've already tried that. I looped through 1000 different decision thresholds (with varying metrics to evaluate the 'best' threshold as well) without managing to improve the classification substantially.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 Thanks! I'll try it out. Meanwhile, are there any other approaches that are not as arbitrary as a subjective ocular inspection?

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 My main issue with your suggestion is that they are better suited for continuous variables. In my dataset, a majority of the included variables are categorical (but also a few continuous variables). What exploratory analysis would you suggest for this case?